# How to swap out widget element based on data

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

We have a GWT project using **RequestFactory**, **Editor Framework** and **UiBinder**. Once the data is loaded from the server using RequestFactory, we determine whether the page should be read-only based on a status in the data.

At this point I would like to render either an `input` widget or a `label` (if read-only).

Ideally I would swap out the rendering of the widget depending on the data, however by the time that the data is loaded it looks like the rendering side has been completed (based on debugging I've done).

I don't want to have two widgets on the page with one hidden. This has caused us issues already with data from the hidden one overriding the other, not to mention the impact of twice the number of widgets in the DOM.

One thought so far was to removeFromParent() when the data was received. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**My first idea is...**

*Only works for input fields and textareas. If you have dropdowns, radioboxes or checkboxes it doesn't work...*

...to style an input field via css so it doesn't look like one (remove border and background color should do it) and disable it if its read only. If its not read only remove the css class, so it looks like a normal input field and make it editable.

Something like this:

```
<style>
.label {
    background-color: white;
    border: 0px;
    color: black;
}
</style>

<input type="text" class="label" disabled value="Read only data"/>
<input type="text" value="Editable data"/>
```

**An other idea is..**

It has been some time that I was using GWT. But can't you just add the widget in the callback from the rcp call where you get the data?

Something like this:

In the ui Binder you just have the container for the data.

In a method you draw the Data as Label or Input field in the container, depending on the data you get. You call this method in the callback from the data request.

Comment: I'm already styling the inputs so they appear as text but this doesn't work for dropdowns, checkboxes or radio buttons. I see your point about the second idea. Seems like a valid approach. I'll give it a go and post some code.

Comment: Yes your right, my first idea only works for text input fields and textareas. I have edited my post.